# Using vcpkg and compiling in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, vcpkg

I am trying to compile (by porting) some code in Windows 10 that was originally developed for Linux.

The code depends on 2 external libraries: `cppkafka` and `librdkafka`.

I saw that `vcpkg` is able to get the libraries, compile them, and then make them automatically available in Visual Studio 2015 (through the `vcpkg integrate install` command).

I see that the `vcpkg` compiles the dependencies for windows 64 (`cppkafka` and `librdkafka`) properly, as the .dll, .lib... are all made available on the install folder of `vcpkg`.

When I try compiling my code in Visual Studio 2015, I see errors concerning the dependencies headers, which for me is unexpected. If `vcpkg` compiled them, why Visual Studio doesn't? From the `vcpkg` documentation, I assume they use the same compiler. Next I show some example errors I am getting:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: AndreKafkaDriver, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>C:\...\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\librdkafka/rdkafka.h(64): error C2371: 'ssize_t': redefinition; different basic types
1>  C:\Siemens\Automation\WinCC_OA\3.16\api\include\winnt\win32.h(47): note: see declaration of 'ssize_t'
1>c:\...\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\cppkafka\header_list.h(265): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'ssize_t', possible loss of data
1>C:\...\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\cppkafka/utils/buffered_producer.h(1035): error C2065: 'queue1': undeclared identifier
1>C:\...\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\cppkafka/utils/buffered_producer.h(1035): error C2065: 'queue2': undeclared identifier
1>C:\...\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\cppkafka/utils/buffered_producer.h(1035): error C2065: 'mutex': undeclared identifier
1>C:\...\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\cppkafka/utils/buffered_producer.h(1035): error C2275: 'std::mutex': illegal use of this type as an expression
1>C:\...\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\cppkafka/utils/buffered_producer.h(1035): note: see declaration of 'std::mutex'
1>C:\...\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\cppkafka/utils/buffered_producer.h(1035): error C2182: 'swap_queues': illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\...\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\cppkafka/utils/buffered_producer.h(1035): error C2470: 'cppkafka::BufferedProducer<BufferType,Allocator>::swap_queues': looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list; skipping apparent body
1>C:\...\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\cppkafka/utils/buffered_producer.h(1035): error C2072: 'cppkafka::BufferedProducer<BufferType,Allocator>::swap_queues': initialization of a function
1>kafkaHWService.cxx(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'execinfo.h': No such file or directory
...
```

Thanks in advance,

Nerea

Comment: You probably want to add a bug report at the `vcpkg` github site.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did it! :)

Comment: I saw your bug report the other day.[https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/10282](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/10282) my suggestion is next time you have a bug report for vcpkg is to put the name of port or ports that are the problem in the title of the question. That way people who know the port have a better chance of seeing the bug report.

Comment: Okey, I'm new here as you probably have noticed :)
Thanks!